# How can I evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x^4)}{x^a(e^x-1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus

I can't evaluate this kind of integral.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^4)}{x^a(e^x-1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

whereas: $a\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: First of all, people who down vote this question have seriously some problems. Second: what is $a$? You shall define it.

Comment: a is a general number. Then, for every different a you could have different solutions.

Comment: For convergence, $\operatorname{Re}(a)\lt3$.

Comment: $a\in\mathbb{R}$

I've edited the question.

Comment: Some context would be nice. Where did you encounter this integral?

Comment: In an exam of analysis.

Comment: @VonNeumann: there are some reasonable explanations for downvotes: for instance, the complete lack of context. An explicit form (as a series involving values of the $\zeta$ function) is not difficult to derive, but I doubt the point of the original question was *to compute* such integral. My bet is on discussing convergence according to the value of $a$, and that is not difficult too. Anyway, the OP should have included some extra information/attempt.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x^4)}{x^a (e^x - 1)^2}\ dx = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x^4)}{x^a e^{2x}} \frac{1}{(1 - e^{-x})^2}\ dx = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}(k+1) \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-kx} \frac{\sin(x^4)}{x^a e^{2x}}\ dx$$

By writing

$$\sin(x^4) = \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix^4} - e^{-ix^4}\right)$$

we can arrange the integral to

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}(k+1)\frac{1}{2i} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x(k+2)}\left(\frac{e^{ix^4} - e^{-ix^4}}{x^a}\right)\ dx $$

Defining for simplicity $s = k+2$:

$$\sum_{s = 2}^{+\infty}(s-1)\frac{1}{2i} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-xs}\left(\frac{e^{ix^4} - e^{-ix^4}}{x^a}\right)\ dx $$

At this point, methods may differ according to ideas.

- Use the stationary phase method
- Use other numerical methods
- See the round bracket as a $F(x)$ function, which'd turn the integral into a (HARD) Laplace Transform
- Use Taylor Series for the second Exponential term, the negative one
- Some counter integration (?)
- $\ldots$ Use your fantasy, but stay on $\mathbb{R}$

And in any case: **beware of $a$**, it may make things to diverge...

Comment: Could you explain how, in the first line you were able to pull out the sum from the integrand?